# How to add Photoshop files to android with some tips on material design

Tags: android, photoshop

I have a doubt.

How to design a user interface in Photoshop and grab that PS files and then place them into Android Studio and apply them to our app.
I really need help for this so please do not close this question.

Any video tutorials or websites which would help me out would be really appreciated.

I really want to start developing apps and put them in the Play Store with great material design and transitions plus great user interface.

Any help for material design?

Comment: `grab that PS files and then place them into android studio and apply them to our app.` If you mean **PSD** files, they **can't be used in Android**. You must extract the images out of them.

Answer (score 0):

You simply canno't do that.
Android can't handle psd file by default.
I believe there exists some exporters that can do that.
Maybe something [like that](http://exportkit.com/learn/how-to/export-your-psd/convert-a-psd-to-android-xml-ui-and-java) would be useful.

Comment: So how does these great material design apps in play store are created??    I mean how do great transitions come into action, does it requires heavy coding ? And tutorials I have seen on Internet suggest that create layout in Photoshop and then import them either in form of png . My actual question is that can such great UI requires hefty coding or not. Is this easy? And I am so sorry for my silly doubts but in this way I would clear all my doubts

Comment: It is not particularly difficult. The best way to achieve a good UI (in my opinion) is simply to create xml layouts.
Obviously, you will need some assets that you can create in photoshop (such as icons) and export it in png or jpg.
However, you can build a very professional UI without using images, simply by creating good styles or downloading them from the internet.
For more information about styles, you can go there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Any other site instead of office site for android developers. Thanks for great reply

Comment: If it is more convenient for you to watch Youtube videos, I would advise you to take a look at this one : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6c3DGnvefY
It helped me a bit when I began.